# Extracting Predictions from Bayesian Random Effects Model (JAGS)

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I'm new to Bayesian, and I'm trying to extract predictions and credible intervals for graphing purposes and can't quite figure out how to code it. Ideally, I'd like both an overall prediction (such as prediction values of dist_feed compared between the two treatments) and prediction values explicitly including the other variables (such as comparing male vs female within each treatment and nesting females vs nesting males within each treatment). Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**model:**

```
sink("dist_feeder.jags") 
cat("
model {

for( r in 1 : Ndata ) {
dist_feeder[r] ~ dnorm(mu[r] , tau) 
mu[r] <-  alphanobo[nobo[r]] + b0[nobo[r]]*treatment[r] + b1[nobo[r]]*sex[r] + b2[nobo[r]]*nest[r] +b3[nobo[r]]*nest[r]*sex[r] + b4[nobo[r]]*brood[r]+ b5[nobo[r]]*brood[r]*sex[r]
}


for (i in 1:Nnobo) { alphanobo[i] ~ dnorm(0, taunobo)
                      b0[i] ~ dnorm(mutreatment,tautreatment)
                      b1[i] ~dnorm(mu1G , tau1G )
                      b2[i] ~dnorm(mu2G , tau2G)
                      b3[i] ~dnorm(mu3G , tau3G )
                      b4[i] ~dnorm(mu4G , tau4G )
                      b5[i] ~dnorm(mu5G , tau5G )
                      }

munobo ~ dnorm(0,0.01)

tau <- 1/(sigma*sigma)
sigma ~ dunif(0,500) 

taunobo <- 1/(sigma.nobo*sigma.nobo)

sigma.nobo ~ dunif(0,500)

mutreatment ~ dnorm(0,0.01) 
tautreatment ~ dgamma(0.1,0.1)

mu1G ~ dnorm(0,.01)
tau1G ~ dgamma(.1,.1)

mu2G ~ dnorm(0,.01)
tau2G ~ dgamma(.1,.1)

mu3G ~ dnorm(0,.01)
tau3G ~ dgamma(.1,.1)

mu4G ~ dnorm(0,.01)
tau4G ~ dgamma(.1,.1)

mu5G ~ dnorm(0,.01)
tau5G ~ dgamma(.1,.1)

 }

",fill = TRUE)
sink()


 ni <- 55000
 nt <- 1
 nb <- 25000
 nc <- 3
 parameters <- 

 c("munobo","sigma", "alphanobo","sigma.nobo","mutreatment", 
   "tautreatment","b0","b1", "b2","b3","b4","b5","mu1G","mu2G", 
   "mu3G","mu4G","mu5G","tau1G","tau2G","tau3G","tau4G","tau5G")

mod1 <- jagsUI(jags.data, inits=NULL, parameters, "dist_feeder.jags", n.chains = nc, n.thin = nt, n.iter = ni, n.burnin = nb)
```

**attempt at prediction extraction code:**

```
pred_fdist <-matrix(nrow=80000,ncol=2)

for(i in 1:80000){
 pred_fdist[i,] <- mod1$sims.list$mutreatment[i] + mod1$sims.list$munobo[i] + mod1$sims.list$mu1G[i] + mod1$sims.list$mu2G[i] + mod1$sims.list$mu3G[i] + 
mod1$sims.list$mu4G[i] + mod1$sims.list$mu5G[i]
}
```